# Extract NA Values in Summary Output of glm

Tags: r, na, purrr, glm

I am running a logistic regression on many different subsets of a large data frame. To do so, I use the follwoing code (using `dplyr`and `purrr`):

```
# define model to be run
mod_fun <- function(df) {
  glm(presence ~ transect, data = df, family = "binomial")
}

# nest data and run model
mod.glm <- dat %>%
  nest(-c(region, fYear, species, road)) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, mod_fun))

# define functions to extract model coefficients
b_fun <- function(mod) {
  coef(summary(mod))[2]
}
p_fun <- function(mod) {
  coef(summary(mod))[8]
}

# extract coefficients
slope<-mod.glm %>% group_by(species, region, fYear, road) %>%
  transmute(beta = map_dbl(model, b_fun),
            p_val = map_dbl(model, p_fun))
```

As you can see, I only want to extract the estimate and p-value of the slope (called `transect`). To do so, I use the indexing `coef(summary(mod))[2]`etc. The problem is that there are also some subsets in my data frame resulting in over-determined systems where some coefficients will be set to NA. Using `coef(summary(mod))[2]` extracts the 2nd value of the `coef()`output and as NAs are ignored in `coef()`, this will no longer be the estimate of `transect` I want to extract. So far I tried unsing `coef(summary(mod_2), complete = TRUE)`(--> nothing changes, NAs still not showed) and adressing the values directly `coef(summary(mod_2), complete = TRUE)["transect","Estimate"]`(--> throws an error). Does anyone know how I could solve this issue?

What I tried so far:

```
# two example models; mod_2 will result in NAs
mod_1 <- glm(presence ~ transect, data = dat[dat$fYear == 1&  dat$species=="Plantago lanceolata",], family = "binomial")
mod_2 <- glm(presence ~ transect, data = dat[dat$fYear == 2&  dat$species=="Plantago lanceolata",], family = "binomial")

coef(summary(mod_1))[2] # works fine
coef(summary(mod_2))[2] # not the value I want

coef(summary(mod_1), complete = TRUE)["transect","Estimate"] # works fine
coef(summary(mod_2), complete = TRUE)["transect","Estimate"] # error

coef(summary(mod_2), complete = TRUE) # NAs for transect are still not displayed

summary(mod_2)$coefficients["transect","Estimate"] # is not working either
```

Data:

```
dput(dat)
structure(list(region = c("HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", 
"HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", 
"HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", 
"HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI", "HWI"), road = c("MK", "MK", 
"MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", 
"MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", 
"MK", "MK", "MK", "MK", "MK"), transect = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 1L), fYear = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), species = c("Plantago lanceolata", 
"Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", "Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", 
"Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", "Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", 
"Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", "Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", 
"Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", "Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", 
"Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", "Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", 
"Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", "Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", 
"Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata", "Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata"
), presence = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -29L), groups = structure(list(
    fYear = c(1L, 1L, 2L), road = c("MK", "MK", "MK"), species = c("Plantago lanceolata", 
    "Poa pratensis", "Plantago lanceolata"), .rows = list(c(1L, 
    3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L
    ), c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 24L, 
    26L, 28L), 29L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about `coef(mod)[["transect"]]`?

Comment: I can't believe it - but this works! Thank you very much. Do you know why this includes NAs and ````coef(summary(mod_2), complete = TRUE)["transect","Estimate"]```` doesn't? And any idea how I could extract the NA p-value?

Comment: If you look at the `str()` of the coefficients in `summary(mod)`, it really looks like the NA rows aren't included.  Run `coef(summary(mod_2), complete = TRUE)` and you won't get the "transect" row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see how to extract the `NA` rows from the coefficients table. The answer, instead, may be to add in the `NA` rows after extracting the elements you want.  This can be done with `complete()`.

In this example I use `broom::tidy()` because it makes it easy to get coefficients, a measure of uncertainty, and results of tests.  This means I have to filter out the intercepts after the fact, but you could certainly do something similar with your functions if you add a column to `complete()` on.

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mod.glm %>%
     group_by(species, region, fYear, road) %>%
     transmute(results = map(model, broom::tidy) ) %>%
     unnest(results) %>%
     complete(term = "transect") %>%
     filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>%
     ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 9
  species          region fYear road  term    estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>            <chr>  <int> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Plantago lanceo~ HWI        1 MK    transe~  -42.7   31127.     -0.00137   0.999
2 Plantago lanceo~ HWI        2 MK    transe~   NA        NA      NA        NA    
3 Poa pratensis    HWI        1 MK    transe~   -0.206     0.188  -1.10      0.272
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great answer. In addition to solving my NA-problem it turns out that ````broom::tidy()````also is much faster than my functions when run on my full (very big) data set. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Going a completely different route, you could change your extraction functions to return `NA` when they give errors.  This is a job for functions like `tryCatch()`, but I've found `possibly()` from **purrr** to be pretty handy for this sort of task.

`possibly()` wraps around a function.  The `otherwise` arguments says what value to return if an error occurs when using the function.

Here are your two functions, wrapped in `possibly()`.  I've changed them to specifically be working with the "transect" row of the coefficients summary so this will error if that doesn't exist.

```
b_fun <- possibly(
     function(mod) {
          coef(summary(mod))["transect", 1]
          }, otherwise = NA)

p_fun <- possibly(
     function(mod) {
          coef(summary(mod))["transect", 4]
          }, otherwise = NA)

# extract coefficients
mod.glm %>%
     group_by(species, region, fYear, road) %>%
     transmute(beta = map_dbl(model, b_fun),
               p_val = map_dbl(model, p_fun) ) %>%
     ungroup() 

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  species             region fYear road     beta  p_val
  <chr>               <chr>  <int> <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Plantago lanceolata HWI        1 MK    -42.7    0.999
2 Poa pratensis       HWI        1 MK     -0.206  0.272
3 Plantago lanceolata HWI        2 MK     NA     NA
```

Comment: This is also great, thanks! Will keep it in mind if I ever happen to be stuck with a similar problem (i.e. functions giving back errors).